# How to enable Disk I/O monitoring

Tags: opennms

I'm having difficulties in enabling/configuring SNMP monitoring of disk i/o in opennms version 1.16.0.3.

So let's explain this a bit. In OpenNMS when you go to "Configure OpenNMS>Operations>Manage SNMP Collections and Data Collection Groups" you can configure SNMP data collection.

In "Data collections Group" select "netsnmp.xml" data collection group file, there you'll find DIsk IO (UCD-SNMP MIB).

My question is: how can this resource (Disk IO) be monitored so that it will appear as a graph in: Nodes>"name of monitored node">Resource graphs

Comment: It's not really clear what information you are looking for.

Comment: just added more details.

Answer (score 0):

In the data collection config file (netsnmp.xml), you need to include the collection group in the system definition toward the bottom of the config file.

You'll notice that the group is called "ucd-diskio"

System definitions (systemDef in the config file) are used to create profiles of metric groups you wish to include for collection attempts.  They use sysOID or sysOID masks to identify devices to attempt collections upon.  So find

(that uses a sysoidMask of .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3)

and add another includeGroup to it of

ucd-diskio

Then just do a touch on $OPENNMS-HOME(dir)/etc/datacollection-config.xml and afer a few minutes, if OpenNMS can collect successfully against your node, you should see the IO data populating.

NOTE: Because disk io is using indexed collections against a MIB table, the graphs will appear under a Disk IO Index heading and not under the catchall Host Resources group of graphs.  It should using something like the volume name to index.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your response. The configuration example from your post is correct, my initial configuration was correct also. The disk i/o worked from the beginning, I just didn't know this until I checked a linux system that was monitored by opennms. The problem is that windows server 2012 doesn't report SNMP disk i/o status. I'll try with snmp-informant, this seems to have disk i/o reporting.